# Unable to create a new step in the odb file in Aabqus Explicit

Tags: python, explicit, abaqus, odb

I am unable to create a new step in the odb file of a dynamic explicit analysis. I am using the following commands to create a new step:

```
odbWrite=openOdb(path="C:\blahblah.odb" , readOnly = False)

newResultsStep=odbWrite.Step(name='Test-a',description='User Defined Results',domain=TIME, timePeriod=1)
```

After the above command, I am getting a message as "Interaction cannot be used with the current procedure".

I have a surface to surface contact as one interaction and a coupling using a RP to a face of a part. These are the only two interactions I have in the model
I have successfully used the same set of commands to create a new step for a static analysis in Abaqus Standard but it does not seem to work in explicit. Kindly help me figuring out a way to create a new step in the odb file for this analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Abaqus distinguishes between interaction properties for implicit and explicit analysis. You just should reassign the interactions for the explicit model and it will solve your problem.